# Is it possible to query the max number of channels available in an ssh connection?

Tags: ssh, connection, channel, transfer, openssh

I'm using ssh to connect to a server (really a cluster, but that's not important) and to transfer files to it. There seems to be a hard limit (9 in this case) of channels that can be used in one ssh connection.

Does the ssh protocol have a mechanism for querying the max number of channels available per ssh connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to query the maximum amount of channels available. The protocol is described in [PROTOCOL.mux](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/PROTOCOL.mux).

The server can limit the amount of multiplexed sessions (`MaxSessions` in `sshd_config`), but not the amount of the channels.

Comment: What's a "channel"? I came here looking for a limit on port forwardings, which I think qualifies as a channel? As far as I can tell, "channels" are included in "sessions", so bumping `MaxSessions` should work. This is because the `PROTOCOL.mux` that you link includes details of requesting port forwardings. I can't find any common multiplexing use of an ssh connection that wouldn't (according to `PROTOCOL.mux` be included in `MaxSessions`. Thank you for linking it!